# Android app user-agent

Tags: android

Случаем не знаете, если я с Android приложения, например, отправляю запрос на http://site.ru/test.php, то какой-нибудь user-agent присваивается?

Comment: В принципе любой. Каким образом вы отправляете запрос? Больше кода, подробностей.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, нет никакого кода. К примеру, возьмём приложение "ВКонтакте для Android", вот когда с него запрос шлётся, какой user-agent приходит на сервера ВК? По умолчанию хотелось бы знать, какой UA шлётся из приложения, скачанных с Play Market.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, а если USER_AGENT, "Custom user agent" не писать, по умолчанию UA пустой становится? Речь о приложениях с Play Market.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, вот это и хотел узнать:

>> Маркет не устанавливает в приложениях свой UA. Это делают (или не делают) программисты написавшие конкретные приложения.

Превратите свой комментарий в ответ, помечу как правильный.

Comment: Читайте больше о https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST , чтобы понимать, как происходят запросы между приложениями и серверами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User-agent - это заголовок http запроса. В него можно написать все что угодно.
Что шлет вконтакт, мне неведомо, я не хостю ни приложение вконтакта, ни доступа к серверам не имею. Вполне возможно, что user-agent они вовсе не шлют. Что шлет браузер серверу, прописано в браузере. Вот в опере я могу задать, чтоб она представлялась и IE и Oper'ой и FireFox'ом...
Конкретно apache (HttpGet, HttpPost) шлет `Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE(java 1.4)`.
А так можно вписать все что угодно:

```
client.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "Custom user agent");
```

Нет понятия "приложения с Play Market". Маркет не устанавливает в приложениях свой UA. Это делают (или не делают) программисты, написавшие конкретные приложения.
см. [SO: Android HTTP User Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904467/android-http-user-agent)

ЗЫ Перенесено из комментариев.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Конечно, присваивается.

Например:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ru-ru; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
```

или

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.4; en-us; HTC Desire Build/GRJ22) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1
```

ну и так далее...

**Обновление**

Значение user-agent зависит от: модели телефона, версии ОС, используемого движка браузера. Самый простой способ - создать php-скрипт с кодом `<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; ?>` и запросить его через стандартный браузер конкретного телефона. Получите строку, которая представляет собой user-agent браузера по умолчанию, который, скорее всего, и используется приложением.

Comment: @Magos, а именно с приложения какой? (скаченное с Play Market)

Comment: Обновил ответ.